# Заглавные/строчные

Tags: орфография, ономастика

"Ленинградское К/краснознаменное военно-инженерное училище" — как правильно пишется?

Answer (score 1):

Пишется **"Ленинградское Краснознаменное военно-инженерное училище"**. По поводу слова *Ленинградское* в Правилах русской орфографии и пунктуации есть разъяснение: с прописной буквы пишутся входящие в состав полного официального названия географические определения, напр.: Калининградское издательство «Деловой мир». Что касается слова *Краснознаменное*, то оно тоже пишется с прописной, потому что училище награждено орденом Красного Знамени (название ордена пишется с прописной), прилагательное входит в официальное название учебного заведения.

Comment: Вот насчет ордена разъяснение не очень внятное. Название ордена - да, с заглавной, а вот прилагательное от него - это должна быть какая-то самостоятельная мотивация. Да, Краснознаменный - везде с заглавной, но почему, из ваших разъяснений не видно.